# Can not insert a source in a <img> tag on XSLT

Tags: xml, image, xslt

Im trying to insert an image on an xslt, but I have problems with the attribute "src", because I can't get the url from the xml. I watched some posts asking about the same, but I didn't get any clearly response. I think most of the problems are caused because the tags have an g: with the valor inside it.

This is a part of my code for the XLst:

```
<xsl:template match='g:image_link'>
<a><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="../g:link" /></xsl:attribute>     
<xsl:element name="img">
  <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="../g:image_link" /></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="width">122</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="height">141</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="border">0</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:value-of select="../g:title" /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element></a>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

And this the XLM part

```
<item>
  <g:title>Title</g:title>
  <g:image_link>url.jpg</g:image_link>
  <g:link>url</g:link>
</item>
```

Thanks in advance.

//EDIT

Thanks for the answers. I could optimize the code a little bit thanks to @torabuzo , but I'm still having problems adding the link of  on the "src" of the image tag. The result it's to add this information into a newsletter, inside on email marketing plataform.

```
<xsl:template match='item'>   
 <xsl:if test="g:id=1702">                         
   <table summary="" width="250" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="producto" align="left">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
       <tr>
        <td height="122" width="141">   
           <a href="{g:link}"><img src="{g:image_link}" width="122" height="141" border="0" alt="{g:title}" /></a> 
        </td>
        <td style="font-family:Century Gothic; font-weight:300; text-align:center; color:#999; font-size:12px; text-align:left">
          <del><xsl:value-of select="g:price" /><xsl:text>€</xsl:text></del>
           <br /><span style="font-family:Century Gothic; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; color:#EE2B7A; font-size:18px"><xsl:value-of select="g:price" /><xsl:text>€</xsl:text></span>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; padding-right:15px">
       <span style="font-family:Century Gothic; font-weight:bold; color:#000; font-size:14px; text-transform: uppercase"><br /><xsl:value-of select="g:title" /></span>
       <br /><br />
        <xsl:value-of select="g:description" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>      
       <br /><br /><br />
        <a href="{g:link}"><img src="url/image.jpg" width="137" height="24" border="0" alt="Comprar" /></a>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <br /><br /><br /> 
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><hr align="left" style="border:none; background-color:#256579; color: #256579; height: 1px; width: 230px"></hr>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
 </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Which result do you want? Which result do you get?  And if namespaces matter then please show minimal but complete samples declaring the namespaces.

Comment: There are namespace prefixes in the fragment (the "g:"). Namespaces matter, must be declared, and must agree.

Comment: I doubt if you want `../g:image_link`, although it might work. Anyway, why are you writing it this way, instead of just `<img src="{.}" width="122" height="141" border="0" alt="{../g:title}">`?